# sed php.ini memory_limit

Tags: bash, php.ini, sed

The following works great:

```
phpmemory_limit=256M #or what ever you want it set to
sed -i 's/memory_limit = 16M/memory_limit = '${phpmemory_limit}'/' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

If the memory_limit is set to 16M, but I've found that in some distributions it doesn't default to 16M, but instead will default to 32M.  So my question is how to I have SED account for that and replace whatever the number is to ${phpmemory_limit}?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use regexp - for instance:

```
phpmemory_limit=256M #or what ever you want it set to
sed -i 's/memory_limit = .*/memory_limit = '${phpmemory_limit}'/' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that:

- Values will always be specified in Mb.
- You wish to preserve trailing comments.
- You don't wish to modify any commented occurances.
- `phpmemory_limit` only contains an integer.

  ```
  sed -ri 's/^(memory_limit = )[0-9]+(M.*)$/\1'${phpmemory_limit}'\2/' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
  ```

This uses..

- Backreferences to shorten the regex and preserve the comment.
- `sed`s extended regex support.
- It's important that the shortened options are specified in that order, otherwise it will create a backup with the file extension `r`.